# Joining User Table To Two Different Tasks table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, inner-join

I have a question on joining user table in this query I built for our business. It's a small productivity report based on 7 different tasks that were completed by the user.

there are two tasks tables:
1) Checklist Task
2) Requested Task

Requested tasks are an extension of Checklist Task. 
Requested tasks have REQUESTED DATE column which is in the Requested Task Table
Requested tasks have COMPLETED DATE column which is in the Checklist Task table.

When I run the query below, obviously the SecurityIdentity Table which is only joined by the Checklist Task table by CompletedByID to display their full name.

The Task name 'Recorded Docs' which is a Requested Checklist, has Requested Date (RequestedDate from Requested Task table) and Received Date (CompletedDate from Checklist table), coming from two different tables as mentioned above.

```
SELECT o.number   AS 'OrderNo',
       s.fullname AS 'CPC Emp',
       Max(CASE
             WHEN t.description = 'Loan Package to Lender' THEN
             Dateadd(hour, -4, t.completeddate)
             ELSE NULL
           END)   AS 'Loan Pck To Lender',
       Max(CASE
             WHEN t.description = 'Recording Audit' THEN
             Dateadd(hour, -4, t.completeddate)
             ELSE NULL
           END)   AS 'Recording Audit',
       Max(CASE
             WHEN t.description = 'Recorded Docs' THEN
             Dateadd(hour, -4, rt.requesteddate)
             ELSE NULL
           END)   AS 'Recorded Docs Requested',
       Max(CASE
             WHEN t.description = 'Recorded Docs' THEN
             Dateadd(hour, -4, t.completeddate)
             ELSE NULL
           END)   AS 'Recorded Docs Received',
       Max(CASE
             WHEN t.description = 'Recorded Docs to Lender' THEN
             Dateadd(hour, -4, t.completeddate)
             ELSE NULL
           END)   AS 'Recorded Docs to Lender',
       Max(CASE
             WHEN t.description = 'Recorded Docs to Purchaser' THEN
             Dateadd(hour, -4, t.completeddate)
             ELSE NULL
           END)   AS 'Recorded Docs to Purchaser',
       Max(CASE
             WHEN t.description = 'Title Policy to Lender' THEN
             Dateadd(hour, -4, t.completeddate)
             ELSE NULL
           END)   AS 'TP to Lender',
       Max(CASE
             WHEN t.description = 'Title Policy to Purchaser' THEN
             Dateadd(hour, -4, t.completeddate)
             ELSE NULL
           END)   AS 'TP Purchaser'
FROM   pf.orderinfo oi
       INNER JOIN pfm.[order] o
               ON ( o.rootid# = oi.rootid )
       INNER JOIN core.profile op
               ON ( oi.owningprofileid = op.id )
       INNER JOIN zref.orderstatus os
               ON ( oi.orderstatus = os.id )
       INNER JOIN zref.producttype pt
               ON ( o.producttypeid = pt.id
                    AND pt.id <> '15' )
       INNER JOIN pfm.task t
               ON ( t.rootid# = oi.rootid
                    AND ( t.description IN ( 'Loan Package to Lender',
                                             'Recording Audit',
                                                 'Recorded Docs to Lender',
                                             'Recorded Docs to Purchaser',
                                             'Title Policy to Lender',
                                             'Title Policy to Purchaser'
                                             ,
                                                   'Recorded Docs' ) ) )
       LEFT OUTER JOIN pfm.requestedtask rt
                    ON ( rt.rootid# = t.rootid#
                         AND rt.id# = t.id#
                         AND rt.lastid# = t.lastid# )
       LEFT OUTER JOIN core.securityidentity s
                    ON ( s.id = t.completedbyid )
WHERE  ( op.NAME LIKE 'BH104%' -- WNCW Res Profiles Begin.
          OR op.NAME LIKE 'CL170%'
          OR op.NAME LIKE 'CM104%'
          OR op.NAME LIKE 'IN103%'
          OR op.NAME LIKE 'SF107%'
          OR op.NAME LIKE 'AW170%'
          OR op.NAME LIKE 'JW170%'
          OR op.NAME LIKE 'KH170%'
          OR op.NAME LIKE 'PM170%'
          OR op.NAME LIKE 'SC170%'
          OR op.NAME LIKE 'EC102%'
          OR op.NAME LIKE 'MT175%'
          OR op.NAME LIKE 'CU108%'
          OR op.NAME LIKE 'NF106%'
          OR op.NAME LIKE 'GA105%'
          OR op.NAME LIKE 'SL105%'
          OR op.NAME LIKE 'PC135%'
          OR op.NAME LIKE 'PE103%'
          OR op.NAME LIKE 'OC130%'
          OR op.NAME LIKE 'WF130%'
          OR op.NAME LIKE 'SS100%'
          OR op.NAME LIKE 'SO191%'
          OR op.NAME LIKE 'CA115%'
          OR op.NAME LIKE 'DO115%'
          OR op.NAME LIKE 'WC115%'
          OR op.NAME LIKE 'WO115%' --WNCW RES Profiles End.
             AND op.enabled = 1
             AND oi.istemplate = 0
             AND oi.number NOT LIKE '%test%'
             AND oi.number NOT LIKE 'tr%' )
       AND oi.number = 'WC115-13-0048'
       AND s.fullname IS NOT NULL
GROUP  BY s.fullname,
          o.number
ORDER  BY 2 DESC
```

When I query this sql, the result is this in red square:
[image: Result]

However, Stacey did not Request that but Kathy did. So, the result date/timestamp SHOULD be displayed as Kathy requested Recorded Docs and not Stacey.

I've tried many different ways to join the securityidentity table to correct this, but was unable to do so.. Any assistance will be greatly appreciate it!

Here are the three tables:
pfm.task
[image]

pfm.requestedtask
[image]

core.securityidentity
[image]

Comment: Be careful when tagging. This is clearly sql but you also tagged mysql. They are not the same thing.

Comment: In order to answer your question we need some details. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Thanks.. I aded the tables.

Comment: Ummm.....those tables are not even close to workable. You can't start column names with an integer, every column name in a table must be unique and the name can't be NULL unless it is the string literal 'NULL'. Your tables will not work and the inserts will not work. Please try actually testing this stuff.

Comment: Sorry, I tried testing it before posting but have ran into issues. So i extracted the tables.

Comment: Well now you have replaced non-working ddl and sample data with pictures. I can't write queries against pictures and I am not about to spend a ton of time converting pictures into data. If you can post something usable I will help.